# Can you ever make your frosting (or icing) without sugar crunch?

Tags: icing, frosting

Can you ever make your frosting (or icing) without sugar crunch? I use powdered sugar, as I'm supposed to (mixed it with milk and lingonberry juice), but I still feel those crunchy sugar crystals which I'd like to avoid. You can use more liquid, but it'll make it runnier which is not optimal. You can dissolve it and then boil down till thick, but it takes time. You can melt chocolate, but you can't make chocolate frosting (or icing) all the time. Any tips, suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your recipe (ingredients and method) for making your frosting? It will be much easier for folks to identify areas of improvement if they know exactly what you're doing now. Particularly with frosting, which means different things to different people

Comment: @AMtwo I just mixed milk with powdered sugar and a little bit of lingonberry juice, that's it. I didn't measure anything

Comment: where I live (US northeast) mention of "frosting" brings a picture of something more akin to buttercream. Adding that detail to your question might greatly help readers understand _what kind_ of frosting.

Comment: @AMtwo it can't be buttercream in and out, can it?

Comment: Other than the photo, I'm not sure what you're using your frosting for, nor what the pastry is filled with. It could be a custard or curd. Regardless, we would refer to the type of topping you describe as "icing" rather than "frosting"

Comment: 1. stirring longer will help a bit 2. the cornstarch in powdered sugar will always be a bit "gritty," sorry.

Comment: Organic powdered sugar is usually made with tapioca starch, at least in the US, and tapioca starch will thicken things at room temperature, and should be less gritty :)